# dynamically using html ordered lists

Tags: html, jquery-ui, html-lists

I am using Jquery and html to create a grid with an ordered list in a GUI.  The user can dynamically edit the html content in each of the grid cells.  I have two questions:

1. If each of the `li` elements has a `.html` associated with it that the user can edit, how can I iterate through all of the `li` elements to get the current value of the `.html`?  Preferably without having to name each element individually....
2. I want to make the grid customizable by the user. I.e. if the user enters in that they want `2 rows` and `2 cols`, the grid will appear 2x2.  How can I dynamically edit how html appears on the GUI?  If the user wants a 10x10 grid, do I really have to create 100 `li` elements, or what's a better way?

Here is my code for the ordered list.  Right now there are 12 cells.  Thanks!

```
<ol id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: you really have 2 questions (as you already numbered them). You should really post them as separate questions. This makes it easier to us to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you could use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get all the `innerHTML` from a list of elements. The following code would give you a list of the `innerHTML` of each `li` and join them by a comma.

   `$('#selectable li').map(function(v) { return $(this).html() }).get().join(', ');`
2. I am pretty sure that jQuery's [manipulation methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) will assist you in inserting/removing elements. How many cells in grid really is up to your program; you could even allow them to insert 1000 cells. Why not?